# How to change the text color of a flatbutton?

Tags: css, reactjs, meteor, material-design

I am working on meteor with react for cross platform app and using material design.

I want to change the text color of a FlatButton.

I want to make the color of the button match the background color which is #262d37 and the text color of the button white.

I can change the background color but not the text color.

[image]

If not using Flat Button, how can I solve this?

```
< FlatButton backgroundColor="white" label="中" onClick={()=> this.changeToZh()}}/>
```

Comment: All of this is already clearly mentioned in the material designs docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a property [**labelStyle**](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/flat-button) of `FlatButton`, use that to set the `color` of text.

As per [DOC](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/flat-button):

> labelStyl:  object {}   --->  Override the inline-styles of the button's **label**
>   element.

Like this:

```
<FlatButton 
     label="中"  
     labelStyle={{color: 'red'}}            //here
     backgroundColor="white"
     onClick={()=> this.changeToZh()}}
/>
```